# How to run a webpack application forever on a remote CentOs 6.8 server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, centos6

I am about to deploy my first application on a centos 6.8 remote server. Actually this application is a react.js client which uses webpack for packaging. I have been able to copy the project on the server with file zilla, and can only run the application with `npm start` which is translated to `nodemon src/server.js --ignore components` using putty. The issue in this method of running the application is that the application stops running when I close the ssh client. Is there another way of running the application for an indefinite period of time remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldn't do that, because looks like you are trying to use webpack development server in production.

You must generate production build with webpack and serve generated files statically with any web server.

Comment: Ok, I get it but how do I do it?